# Dynamically adding a View to an android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am programmically creating a view at runtime and I want to this view to be added to my linearlayout dynamically at runtime. Here is the code I got:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.main);

        DemoView dv = new DemoView(context);

            // Stuck here...How do I add my new dv View to my android widget

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }


     private class DemoView extends View {
        public DemoView(Context context) {
            super(context);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Paint LedColor = new Paint();
            Paint BlankColor = new Paint();
            Path p,p1;
            Matrix m = new Matrix();

            LedColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            LedColor.setColor(0xffffffff);

            BlankColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            BlankColor.setColor(0xff111111);

            DigitPaths dp = new DigitPaths();

            p = dp.GetDigitPath(-1);
            p1 = dp.GetDigitPath(5);

            p.offset(50, 50);
            p1.offset(50, 50);

            m.setScale(6.5f, 6.5f);
            p.transform(m);
            p1.transform(m);
            canvas.drawPath(p,BlankColor);
            canvas.drawPath(p1, LedColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to add a custom `View` to an app widget.  See [the "Creating the App Widget Layout" section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) of the App Widgets Dev Guide for what `View` types are allowed.

Android 3.0 adds support for some views to display collections.  See [the "Using App Widgets with Collections"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections) section for details.

Otherwise, to dynamically add an allowed `View` to an App Widget, after inflating the `RemoteViews` and getting a reference to it, you can use its `addView(View)` method, or the `addView(View)` method on any of the `View` objects already in the `RemoteViews`.

Answer (score 2):

As Bruce correctly answered, it is not possible to use a custom view. Since it seems like your view doesn't respond to input, and just draws, you can achieve the same functionality with an ImageView. Just create a Bitmap, create a Canvas with it, and then draw on it using what was your onDraw code. Then create an ImageView (which is allowed in a widget) and set the image it displays to your Bitmap.